# .NET Core WEB API - Return 400 if user includes an unrecognized query parameter in the GET URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, query-string

Pretty much as the title says - I want to throw a 400 bad request with a message something along the lines of `Unexpected Query Param: someParam`.

This would help consumers of the API greatly when trying to debug why their calls aren't working, e.g. if they've misspelled a parameter.

I've done a little searching and haven't found anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

Some might say you’re not trying hard enough:

```
return BadRequest(“some error or object”);
```

Comment: Well, yes, duh. I know how to return a response. My question is, is there some automatic way to return such an error when a query param is passed as a part of the URL that isn't defined as one of the query params in the controller method signature.

Comment: Haha fair enough, didn’t quite get that from the question. Tbh I think whilst there would be a way to do this via middleware or filters I think there are various more standard mechanisms that make more sense. Validation on your input models would be one example, validation on your command or query objects if you’re doing some form of CQRS, etc. Whilst generic responses can be useful I suspect a lot of the time the reasons and responses you want to give need to be a bit more contextual and domain specific. My 2c anyway.